# Humidity causes Asko clothes washer to buzz and not start

Tags: appliances, clothes-washer

I have an Asko 20004 Front Loading clothes washer.  When the air is very humid (in the summer) it buzzes when I turn it on but the moter will not start.   I've disassembled it and the buzzing seems to be coming from the motor.

When I run a dehumidifier for a few hours it runs fine.  (Not a fluke, this is the third year I have noticed this phenomena).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have an elderly 20004 excellence that screeches and won't start when humidity is high; a damp laundry room in winter is the problem in my case. Whenever the repair man attended it behaved perfectly.

I decided to investigate the electronic circuit board as that is where the singing seemed to be coming from and found that there is very little protection for this board from the big space surrounding the drum and all those suds. The board had some yellowy brown substance on it (probably detergent residue from an oversuds adventure in the past)  which I carefully and very gently cleaned off with rubbing alcohol, some paper towel and q-tips using a rolling movement so as to minimize damage to the pins and  delicate surface. Be careful not to leave any paper or cotton "crumbs" caught on the sharp bits.  I was amazed at how much dirt was removed and how the washer was instantly fixed.

I have repeated this every winter for the last few years whenever the circuit board sings and have been grateful that the tiny cost of one special screw driver and a gentle clean could prolong the useful life of my washer.

Hope you find a solution for yours.

Comment: That is great information.  Next time it happens, I'll definitely investigate that.   Note: I used a soft rubber house as a "stethoscope".  I held one end up to my ear and moved the other end around the inside of the machine to pinpoint where the noise was coming from...it was the motor.   But, residue on the circuit board could case incorrect signals sent to the motor.

Comment: I took apart the front panel far enough to see the circuit board.   I could see a soapy residue on the board.  I blasted it thoroughly with contact cleaner and I think the problem is fixed now.   Note:  About 2 years ago, I was washing golf balls in the washer and used dish washing detergent instead of low suds.  The soap foam overflowed and came out the soap dispenser.   That is probably what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that moisture is likely causing an electrical short between two wires or connectors, that should not be connected.  It is not uncommon for a motor to hum and not turn when something is shorted out.

Normally I would expect that it would have to be sopping-wet, dripping with water, for this situation to happen.  If it really is just humid, and you don't see the motor dripping with water, then something else is perhaps retaining the water and providing a path for an electrical short.

My guess would be dryer lint from a clothes dryer.  Do you have one right next to your washer?  In my laundry room, even though the clothes dryer is properly vented outside, little leaks here and there still allow lint dust to accumulate around the room.

Open up your washer and clean off all the dust you can find.  Vacuum it thoroughly, and blow any dust out of the motor itself that you can.  If your vacuum has an option to use a hose to blow instead of suck, try that.  Better yet, blow the motor out with an air compressor if you can.  Also, remove any clip-on wire harness connectors, clean them off, and put them back on.

It seems like a *lot* of the things I fix consist of just taking something apart, cleaning it, and reassembling it.

Also, of course, double-check your dryer for cracks in the vent exhaust tubing or other places, and seal them up.

It also could just be the case that two wires inside the motor winding have worn or exposed insulation, and the humidity shorts them out, even without lint dust.  This could be harder to find.  If blowing dust out of the motor doesn't fix it, you may need to disassemble the motor to clean it.  If that doesn't work, and you don't find any obvious-looking problems inside the motor, it may need to be replaced.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'll either get some compressed air to blow out the motor in place or take the motor out and do it.   Hmmm...maybe I can hook up my vacuum cleaner to blow instead of suck.